# How to read specific collection in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two components to login as an 'User' and 'Worker'.Their data s in two collection name as 'users','workers'.This is my 'User Login' function.

```
SignIn(email, password) {
    this.value = this.afs.collection( 'users'  , ref =>
      ref.where('email', '==', email)
    ).valueChanges();
    this.value.subscribe(data => {
      this.datas = data;
      console.log(this.datas )
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((result) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
          });
        }).catch((error) => {
          window.alert(error);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('signinu');
        })
    });
  }
```

So in this function i can login with using 'workers' collection data.That's mean 'Worker' can login with 'User login'component. So how to fix this? please help me.

This is my 'worker login' function

```
SignIn(email, password) {
        this.value = this.afs.collection('workers', ref =>
            ref.where('email', '==', email)
        ).valueChanges();
        this.value.subscribe(data => {
            this.datas = data;
            console.log(this.datas)
            if (this.datas !== null) {
                return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((result) => {
                    this.ngZone.run(() => {
                        this.router.navigate(['/profile/' + this.datas[0].uid]);
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    window.alert(error);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('signinu');
                })
            } else {
                window.alert('Invalid user');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here.

Comment: I'm worker. So now i login as a worker. When i click 'login' button i should go My 'worker profile' page. If i'm user when i login i should go to 'Home page'. So here it's not working. Always direct to 'Home page' even if he 'worker' or 'user'.

Comment: @DougStevenson clear?

Answer (score 1):

In the sign in page, create a dropdown menu where the user can choose if he is a `user` or `worker`, then in the `signin` method add another parameter called `type`:

`SignIn(email, password, type)`

And check if type is equal to `user` then use collection `user` else if type is equal to `worker` then use collection `worker`. When you are retrieving you are already using the `where` to query if the email exists in the `user` collection or the `worker` collection. If a user is `worker` and they clicked on `user`, then since you are doing a query to check the email nothing will be retrieved and you can show an alert.

Comment: I already think this but is it formal thing for login page? Anyway I'll try this and thank you.

Comment: In dropdown menu how to pass the selected value to signin function?  **<div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu  >
                    <button ngbDropdownItem #jobType>user</button>
                    <button ngbDropdownItem #jobType>worker</button>**   and here **(click)="SignIn(useremail.value, userPassword.value, jobType.value )">** but this is not pass the selected value